# I have an error every time i run my react native code on my Simulator but it works on the web

Tags: react-native, npx, sanity

I am creating an application, on react native and i am using sanity cms as my back-end. Once i installed all the packages for sanity there was a package.json that was installed, and in my project once i run npx and create the application by default. there is a package.json aswell. Once i ran the code it said i have a duplicate so i changed the sanity/package.json. Now every time i use the simulator on expo GO I get this weird error and i have tried every thing to fix it...
This is the error:
TypeError: undefined is not a function, js engine: hermes
ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

- Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.

I have tried changing the package.json file. i have tried clearing my cache, i have even restarted the metro and closed vs code and restarted it. I deleted the node modules and re-installed it

Answer (score 1):

i have that error on my react-native project and this is my solution

- npx expo install react-native-reanimated@~2.14.4
- add plugins: ["react-native-reanimated/plugin"], to babel.config.js
- npx expo start -c

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).